# How to put a highlight transparet text on image view?

Tags: android, xml, textview, transparent

i have this view :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="10dp"

        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i need to make that transparent text view like a shadow,that means,i want to make it darker from bottom and lighter from top,from dark in bottom being lighter to top,
but my code is same color whole of text view
but i need to make it like shadow,darker from bottom to lighter to top,my color is Monotone #80000000 i want to make it highlight,like a shadow

how can i do it?

Comment: Change ImageView and textview in FrameLayout to get the desire view you want. Framelayout make the component to overlap.

Comment: tried using alpha property of textview?

Comment: @Clairvoyant if you see my layout, i did that overlap, i need just changing color from same color to a highlight color,my text view trasparent color is #80000000 whole of text view,but i need to make it highlight,like a shadow

Comment: @Salmaan no,i just want to change my color from monotone to highlight

Comment: you should mark answer correct if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML:**

You just need to create a drawable resource (see an example below), and add it to the layout you created for your ListItem.

The drawable (in your res\drawable folder - name it whatever - listgrad.xml for ex) could look like:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
      android:startColor="@color/gradient_start"
      android:endColor="@color/gradient_end"
      android:angle="-270" /> 
</shape>
```

The you would add it to the layout for your list item (the layout.xml file you define for this) like this code snippet:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranking_order"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_grad"
        />
...
```

**JAVA:**

```
TextView secondTextView = new TextView(this);
Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20,
        new int[]{Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE},
        new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);
secondTextView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```